# How to break the count

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
List= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 50, 66, 68, 70, 72, 73, 78, 80, 82, 89, 90, 95, 156, 200, 800, 1000]
gaps = [1]
```

I'm iterating between the List with my gap and I'm getting that the difference between the element of my list in my dict as `1 : 6`

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] has a gap 1  = 4 times
[72, 73] = has a gap 1  = 1 time
[89, 90] = has a gap 1  = 1 time
```

but I want to get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] has a gap 1  = 4 times
```

because they are in series.

I am using a counter but I don't know how to tell to stop the count once the next number is not the correct (`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` next supposed to be 6) but because is not in the list it should stop to count until it find a new series

Comment: Please format the code using ctrl+K and explain neatly what does "enter code here "mean

Comment: @Aditya "enter code here" is the example text that gets inserted when you start writing inline code

Comment: I edited your question to try to fix the formatting. If anything's still wrong, please [edit] to fix it. See the [editing help](/editing-help#code) if needed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. Debugging questions require a [mre], but your code is missing. Please [edit] to add it. Also check out [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: Are you looking for the longest sequence of elements with your desired gap or just the first sequence in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 50, 66, 68, 70, 72, 73, 78, 80, 82, 89, 90, 95, 156, 200, 800, 1000]
gaps = [1]

cpt = 0
for idx in range(len(my_list)):
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    elif (my_list[idx] - my_list[idx - 1]) == gaps[0]:
        cpt += 1
    else:
        break

print(cpt)
>>> 4
```